# Find angle of right angled triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to work out the angle of a right angled triangle. I have an array containing the lengths of the two sides of the triangle. I also have an array containing the Euclidean Distance between these two points. How would I find the angle of the triangles? In other words, how would I do the sin and then arcsin methods to find the angle? I am just looking for the angle opposite of the hypotenuse. I'm trying to do this in C++.

Solved it now, misinterpreted what I had been asked to do

Comment: sin(A) = opposite / hypotenuse, use math to get the angle from that.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? It is easier to help better when we know exactly where you have trouble :)

Comment: The angle opposite of the hypotenuse in a right triangle will always be 90.

Comment: use arcsin with both length to find angle

Comment: All explained [here...](http://youtu.be/fO1Vhc88QkM)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: How would I find the angle of the triangles

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#define radians(x) return x * (180/pi) 

int main()
{

    double opposite, adjacent, angle1, angle2, angle3, choice, radians, hypotenuse;  
    cout << "Opposite: ";
    cin >> opposite;
    cout << "Adjacent: ";
    cin >> adjacent;
    cout << "Radians or Degrees: (R/D)";
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice == "R")
    { 
        angle1 = arctan(adjacent/opposite);
        hypotenuse = opposite\cos(radians(angle1));
        angle2 = arcsin(adjacent\hypotenuse);
        cout << "Angle 1: "<< radians(angle1) << endl;
        cout << "Angle 2: "<< "90\n";  
        cout << "Angle 3: "<< radians(angle2) << endl;
        cout << "Hypotenuse: " << hypotenuse;
    }
    else if(choice = "D")
    {
        angle1 = arctan(adjacent/opposite);
        hypotenuse = opposite\cos((angle1));
        angle2 = arcsin(adjacent\hypotenuse);
        cout << "Angle 1: " << (angle1) << endl;
        cout << "Angle 2: " << "90\n";  
        cout << "Angle 3: " << (angle2) << endl;
        cout << "Hypotenuse: " << hypotenuse;
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

or just

```
angle2 = 180 - (angle1 + 90)
```

Comment: It smells like, but does not parse as C++. Why you posted what you did not try to compile??

Answer (score 0):

The relation between sides and angles of triangle is:-

```
a/sinA = b/sinB = c/sinC
```

where 'a' is the side opposite angle 'A'.

You know one angle let's say it's `A = 90`. Then you can calculate other two angles from above equation.

Comment: It's a generalized solution for any traingle if you know all its side and any one angle...

Answer (score 0):

You have the lengths of the sides, if you us tangents, you can find the angle for the corresponding side.

Also, once you find one angle, all you need to do is subtract 90 from it to get the final angle:

```
tan(angle) = opposite/adjacent;

angle = arctan(opposite/adjacent);

otherAngle = 90 - angle;
```